# NVDA doesn't read buttons in Firefox using Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, accessibility, nvda

I'm having a serious problem with a customer using NVDA as his screen reader with my application.

I preface this with the tests I've done using NVDA + my site:
Chrome: my site works perfectly, but NVDA won't read the browser itself.
Edge: my site and the browser both work, but customer has other issues and won't use it.

In Firefox my buttons aren't read unless I press them (which defeats the purpose).
I've tried adding a button tag directly to the HTML and it gets read, so the problem must lie in Vue or Vuetify.

This is an example for a button I'm using:

```html
<v-btn rounded="0" class="mt-2 bg-white-custom me-3 text-body-2" aria-label="Torna al sito" title="Torna al sito">
      Torna al sito
</v-btn>
```

I've tried changing the `<v-btn>` tag with a simple button and even a `<div>` tag.
I've tried adding a role to it and even various (and many nonsensical) aria tags.

Comment: What's the actual DOM that gets output by this tag? Does the screen reader also fail on [the library sample playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqLrlYqLkrWdywo0CsrTVWyUrIpSc0tyEksSbWLyVNQsCnTTSwoADPBnOT8vJLEzLzUIqgQWDCpJA/OVVBwKi0pyc+DS+sjy4N4qEaARCA22OjDbVaq1VEy1jPRM1cC0aZ6xkqxAA8nMcw=)?

Comment: In the DOM there's a button with the aria attribute and inside a span with its content gets created, in this case 'Torna al sito'. I've tried the codepen and has the same behaviour: works in Chrome, doesn't work in Firefox

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn’t get read? Are you using the tab key to navigate to the button? That wouldn’t work on a `<div>`, that’s why I’m asking. On a side note, you should definitely remove `aria-label` and `title`, they are completely redundant.

Comment: I tried the Playground example with NVDA 2023.3.3 and Firefox 122. There is no issue, I can focus the button, it announces “Button, Button”. Even reading with NVDA+↓ will announce it that way. Can you please try to provide a code snippet in your question that demonstrates the issue for you?

Comment: Have you tried resetting NVDA’s settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries the problem appeared to be Vuetify. Even on their site it won't be read by NVDA on Firefox. I've opted to remove Vuetify and write my frontend again without any library.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the attribute `tabindex=0` so that the button can be focussed. It also makes sense to define the button with `role="button"` to tell the screen reader that it is a button.

Further information on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role

In your case:

```
<v-btn
   rounded="0"
   class="mt-2 bg-white-custom me-3 text-body-2"
   @click.stop="tornaAlSito()"
   aria-label="Torna al sito"
   title="Torna al sito"
   role="button"
   tabindex="0"
>
   Torna al sito
</v-btn>
```

This option must be switched on in NVDA (it's in German, sorry, it means something like: switch on mouse tracking)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried adding those attributes, but it still doesn't work.  Or better, works if cycling elements with TAB, but doesn't work with mouseover

Comment: This is exactly how I use it, except that I don't use `aria-label` in this case, as it is unnecessary due to the Text button. (NVDA Version 2020.3)

Comment: I was using version 2023.3.3, tried the downgrade  but still nothing. I tested on vuetify workspace as the user above suggested and even there doesn't work on Firefox but works on Chrome (without any tag nonetheless)

Comment: By the way, I use a portable version.

Comment: The `tabindex` approach does not seem correct, `v-btn` outputs a native `button` element which is focusable by default, they don't need a `tabindex` attribute for that.

Comment: Checked the configuration and it's enabled. Sadly the customer is from a public ministry, so it's bound to use the software via PC